# Array return at the end one value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

what is the best way to put parents value in the same array ( Concate ) as this code just return one value

```
public function divisionParent($name)
{
    $path = array();
    $path[] = $name; 
    $div = CsiCategory::where('name', $name)->first();
    $parent_id = $div->parent_id;


    if ($parent_id != 0) {
        $name = CsiCategory::where('id', $parent_id)->first();
        $this->divisionParent($name->name);
    }


    return $path;

}
```

Comment: Is CsiCategory's parent another CsiCategory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
public function divisionParent($name, $path = [])
{
    // Append to $path arr.
    array_push($path, $name);

    // Get division by name. 
    $div = CsiCategory::where('name', $name)->first();

    // Check for existing parent division by id.
    if (isset($div)) {
        if ($div->parent_id != 0) {
            $divParent = CsiCategory::where('id', $div->parent_id)->first();
        }
    }

    return isset($divParent) ? $this->divisionParent($divParent->name, $path) : $path;
}
```